# calling a method inside MainActivity from GCM onMessage()

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

i want when a new message received by **onMessage()** inside **GCMIntentService.java** , the **onMessage()**  call a method called **blinkLED()** inside the **MainActivity.java** so the **blinkLED()** method can use the data received by **onMessage()** , how can i implement that ? a sample code will be helpful.

Comment: why you want to call blinkLED()  method inside GCMIntentService ? best way is use SharedPreferences for sotring values and call blinkLED() or get values from SharedPreferences   on Activity onResume to show latest value when Activity start

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use BroadcastReceiver. This [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) shows you how to send a broadcast intent from a class, and have another class handles it.

Short example, in your GCMIntentService::onMessage(), you may have this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.my.app.blinkled");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Then in your MainActivity, you implements a BroadcastReceiver :

```
private class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    blinkLED();
  }
}
```

and register for it in onResume() of MainActivity:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("com.my.app.blinkled");
receiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```