# Not able to refresh current fragment while switching through activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am  using fragments in android. And I want to implement a functionality i.e. if a notification arrives on device then a particular action will he happened on fragment.

**What I have done to implement functionality**
I am doing that if a notification arrives I stored it in shared preference and I am running a handler in my fragment for every second which means when a notification arrives I store value in shared preference and based on it my handler runs and hit web service but I am facing one problem that is if I run code for very first time then it runs perfectly after that if i switch to another activity and then came to that fragment and then a notification arrives my fragment will not be refreshed. Please help me in this regard.Thanks in advance.

**code of gcm intent class**

```
         if(msgg.contains("has been cancelled due to following reason"))
        {
            editor.putString("cancelOrder", "1");
            String[] a1 = msgg.split("#");
            String a2=a1[0];
            String a3 = a1[1];

            String[] part = a3.split(" ");
            String part1 = part[0];

            editor.putString("cancelOrderidnew", part1);
            editor.commit();
            msg = msgg;
        }
```

**code for my fragment**

```
     private final Runnable runforneworder = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {


     String   cancelOrdernew = sp.getString("cancelOrderidnew", null);

        if (cancelOrdernew != null)
        {
            connectToDatabase();
        }

        handler.postDelayed(runforneworder, 1000);
    }
};


public void connectToDatabase() {



 new GetOrders().execute(new Config().newOrd, id);
}
```

Comment: Instead of running your handler for every second you can instead use onNewIntent method of your activity.

Comment: but how can I detect gcm notification from onNewIntent @AbhishekJaiswal

Comment: See for detecting notification you have to use GcmBroadcasteReciever

Comment: I have used it Gcm braodcast reciever and intentservice

Comment: So you should be getting the notification if implemented properly.

Comment: why you are running handler? You can handle it from GcmBroadcasteReciever.

Comment: I am not understanding how can i do it. Please help me. Just give me a basic idea @Exigente05

Comment: Yes, I am getting notifcation properly @AbhishekJaiswal

Comment: On getting the notification create the notification using pending Intent which will redirect to certain Activity. Now if the activities launch mode is default then every time when you click the notification it will create a new Activity in the task, So instead change the launch mode to SingleTask and get intent data in onNewIntent method of your Activity and refresh your fragment accordingly.

Comment: I hope you got your answer now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661749/calling-a-method-inside-mainactivity-from-gcm-onmessage - this might help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252065/refreshing-activity-on-receiving-gcm-push-notification - check this also

Comment: i have used second link but got ths error http://prntscr.com/doe36j @Exigente05

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835970/broadcastreceiver-trying-to-return-result-during-a-non-ordered-broadcast-packa

Comment: I have attached my code but using this code notification are coming indefinately please help https://drive.google.com/a/xlim.org/file/d/0B3tz3FqHp8WFZXVNRlpvdFZyN2c/view?usp=sharing     @Exigente05